# null values not being removed from list

Tags: groovy

I have the following script which I am using to query values from a JSON message and return a list with unique values and non null values.

The syntax is not working and the null values are still there.

```
def uniqueProfiles = jsonpath(r2,'$..[*].estancias[*].huespedes[0].huesped')
def profiles = (uniqueProfiles - null).unique()
```

Comment: Double-check if you are not dealing with null represented as a string. In this case, what you have on that list is not `null` but `'null'`. You can invoke `uniqueProfiles.inspect()` and if you see `'null'` instead of `null`, then this is your issue. The second line of your example removes all `null` values as expected, but it can't remove the `'null'` string.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great answer. Can you write it down as an answer so I can pick that one? @s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check if you are not dealing with `null` represented as a string value. In this case, what you have on that list is not `null` but a `'null'`. You can invoke `uniqueProfiles.inspect()` and if you see `'null'` instead of `null`, then this is your issue. The second line of your example removes all null values as expected, but it can't remove the `'null'` string. There are two solutions:

- avoid capturing `null` values as strings,
- or do `((uniqueProfiles - null) - 'null').unique()`